# Verifying LibreOffice after each restart?

Tags: catalina, verify, libreoffice

Why does macOS need to verify LibreOffice each time after a restart? I haven't updated the app in a while, and after the first verification it opens normally the next time. This is annoying and it takes a long time (about a minute). This should happen once, after installing (in the /Applications folder), not repeatedly. This doesn't happen for other apps.

[image: Verifying Libreoffice App]

**How can I make macOS stop verifying LO after a restart?**

NB: Saw the same happening to Firefox, but not Thunderbird and Evernote.

---

**Update**

I installed this app several months ago. And I mention that this happens after a restart. So I don't open the app from a DMG, which would be unmounted after a restart anyways.

Comment: We can't see your screen, so please help us to understand your setup, and add a screenshot of the message you get.

Comment: What is your setting at https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh11784/10.15/mac/10.15 under allow apps section ?

Comment: LO has access to the Documents folder, but not full disk access. I have no idea where else you want me to look. I don't see what the settings here have to do with my problem. These settings are about when the program is running, which folders it can write to.

Comment: I did a restart to recreate the problem. No Libreoffice DMG in my downloads folder, obviously nothing mounted. Checked the Disks app to be 100% sure. Nothing there of course. After restart: I see it happening again, see the screenshot above. And it happened with Firefox as well.

Comment: @SPRBRN please use @ to ping. I wanted to ask which apps are allowed to run on your mac? Only app store or app store + developers identified by apple.

Comment: @ankii - I download Libreoffice, open the DMG, then copy it to the /Applications folder, then rightclick and choose "open", then a popup appears, asking for permission to run the app. I agree, and that's about it. So it's not "only appstore", but I don't know where you set or change this.

Comment: @SPRBRN https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VFZJ.png

Answer (score 3):

- https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126409

It is a bug filed on LibreOffice's tracker. So they're aware of it. Please do not flood the tracker with "me too" comments.

Answer (score 1):

You still seem to start LibreOffice from the DMG file it was delivered in. Just drag the LibreOffice icon into your `/Applications` folder to install it properly. You can then eject and delete the DMG file.

Comment: No I don't use the DMG

Comment: I tend to agree with @nohillside: you may not be consciously using the .dmg file, but macOS is referring to it every time you launch LibreOffice. Use the .dmg file to install LibreOffice in your computer's Applications folder. Then fInd the .dmg file on your computer, and drag the .dmg file into the Trash. Then restart.

Comment: I did a restart to recreate the problem. No Libreoffice DMG in my downloads folder, obviously nothing mounted. Checked the Disks app to be 100% sure. Nothing there of course. After restart: I see it happening again, see the screenshot above. And it happened with Firefox as well.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you do not have the app installed on your computer, and hence the app config is missing, causing macOS to ask you to verify with every restart.

You should consider installing it as mentioned in [@nohillside's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/391145/279727), by dragging to copy the LibreOffice.app into the `/Applications` directory.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also install the app using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). If you already use Homebrew, you can simply run the following command-line in Terminal.app to install the app:

```
brew cask install libreoffice
```

If you do not have Homebrew installed, you can follow the installation instructions on Homebrew [website](https://brew.sh) to install it before running the above command.

Comment: I have copied the LO app from the DMG to the applications folder, like I always have done.

Comment: I use Brew a lot, didn't realise that Libreoffice can be installed via brew. While it doesn't explain the problem, it might be a solution.